# OnClickListener, cant link it to another xml layout page

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android Studio, and I want to link button to other page, 
but the only problem I have is OnClickListener, please help ;(

**Title.java (main page, page_title.xml)**

```
package com.afinal.xxx.learnk;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.afinal.xxx.learnk.R.styleable.View;

public class Title extends AppCompatActivity {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_title);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.title_learn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Learn.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
};

public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

**^^Title XML's button (RelativeLayout)**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/title_learn"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title_logo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_logo"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:onClick="start"
    android:text="LEARN"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
```

**Learn.java (next page, page_learn.xml)**

```
package com.afinal.xxx.learnk;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Learn extends AppCompatActivity {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_learn);
}

}
```

I'm using Android API 19 for better compatibility, is there any other solution for this problem? Thank you very much :D

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: have you declare  Learn Activity in Manifest file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is correct, but code is wrong.

1. Check your code in onclickListener

   ```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Learn.class);
   ```

this is wrong, use `Title.this` instead of this.

2.Check your Manifest.xml
Register Learn.class in Manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the 'this' in intent to Title.this to 
and you have an extra semicolon after the curly braces of on create function.

Just copy paste this and try for yourself

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.page_title);

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.title_learn);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Learn.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
}
```